# La URL de un Web Worker no funciona en Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con web workers y Angular 7+

Este es app.component.html

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="lat" placeholder="Latitude" #lat (input)="updateMap( lat )">
  <input type="text" name="lng" placeholder="Longitude" #lng (input)="updateMap( lng )">
</div>
```

Este es mi app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'mapa';
  coords: any = {lat: 0, lng: 0};
  worker: Worker;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.worker = new Worker( './app.component.worker.js' );
  }

  updateMap( selector: any ) {
    const key   = selector.getAttribute('name');
    const value = Number(selector.value);
    this.coords[ key ] = value;

    this.worker.postMessage( this.coords );
  }
}
```

Este es mi WebWorker en app.component.worker.js

```
onmessage = ( e ) => {
    console.log( e );
};
```

Todos los archivos están al mismo nivel

```
project
 -e2e
 -node_modules
 -src
   -app
     -app-routing.module.ts
     -app.component.css
     -app.component.html
     -app.component.ts
     -app.component.worker.js
   -lot of files
 -lot of files
```

Cuando inicia la aplicación me aparece

> GET http://localhost:4200/app.component.worker.js 404 (Not Found)

Intenté poniendo una ruta más completa al constructor del Worker

```
'./src/app/app.component.worker.js'
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar

Que estará mal?
Habrá una forma de hacerlo con Angular directo o con typescript?

Answer (score 1):

El fichero de tu worker no se publica y no se incluye ni en el comando `build` ni en el `serve`.

Tienes dos opciones:

Primero: Incluye el fichero del worker en el directorio `assets` de los recursos e incluyelo de esta forma

```
this.worker = new Worker( 'assets/app.component.worker.js');
```

Segundo: Agrega una entrada al `angular.json` en `appname -> architect -> build -> options -> assets`. Lo que escribas en ese arreglo es incluido en el build y se encuentra disponible como un fichero publico aunque te recomiendo usar la carpeta `assets` si tienes muchos ficheros para que te quede más organizado. El worker lo usarías así

```
this.worker = new Worker('app.component.worker.js');
```